# PHP/MySQL Query and String Concatenation of row from mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql, string

This works:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$accountID = $row['accountID'];
queryMysql('INSERT INTO accounts (accountID, password) VALUES (' .
           "'$accountID'" . ', \'a\')');
```

But this doesn't:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
queryMysql('INSERT INTO accounts (accountID, password) VALUES (' .
           $row['accountID'] . ', \'a\')');
```

Why?

Comment: `queryMysql()` is not a function and `$accountID` in undefined, so technically neither should work.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was using a function I made myself to make MySql queries cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're missing another ' right before and after $row['accountId']

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
queryMysql('INSERT INTO accounts (accountID, password) VALUES (\'' .
           $row['accountID'] . '\', \'a\')');
```

If you are beginning PHP and have the required version of PHP (5.1.0) I strongly suggest you start using PDO

http://php.net/pdo

instead of the standard mysql_*

Comment: Thanks for the PDO pointer, I'll look more into that!. Adding a single quote before and after $row['accountID'] doesn't work though - isn't that a string literal? I originally did it the second way because of http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_select.asp..The accountID column is type int.

Comment: Yes, to php that is a string literal, but when you pass in to mysql, it has to be a string literal in a string literal. If you are confused by that, start using PDO :P.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should always tell us *why* it doesn't work. Only saying "it doesn't work" is really begging for getting your post ignored.

Second, the cause of the error is most likely the lack of quote, but that would only be necessary if there's another underlying problem. The type of the column accountID seems to be varchar or text. An ID should be an integer.

You have to wrap your value with quotes if it's a string, you don't if it's an integer.

Comment: The accountID column is type int; why does it seem like it's varchar?

Comment: @Sarah, because it raises an error if you don't use quotes. Quotes aren't necessary for integers. Please tell us WHAT IS THE PROBLEM. Nobody wants to guess, saying "it doesn't work" is *really* unhelpful.